# Fetch network name while typing mobile number in ionic

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, bower, ngcordova

In my ionic v1 app, I want to get the network name automatically as selected in the dropdown list while typing my mobile number like recharge websites like paytm, etc. Any ideas how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I assume by using this plugin : https://github.com/pbakondy/cordova-plugin-sim

You can get your carrierName